# Android Keypad pushing layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I think it question pretty simple, and everybody faced with same issue. In my case, everything is same. And I searching just a better solution.

I have a lot of nested elements. I have activity, which contains several Fragment (Refer to the Image). One of them, located on the Bottom, and has less height. I have edit text, which contains in second Fragment.

[image]

When I selected EditText, keypad overlap View for typing. So can easily create behavior and add some padding(or margin, or Space view). Or add animation to move up EditText.

But I prefer to use SoftInputType, to adjust Views. But for some reason, changing SoftInputType doesn't effect! So suppose, it's because nested elements, or fragment, how I can fix this, to use code below, as expected?

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the following line in your android manifest file where your activity is defined:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

For example:

```
<activity
  android:name="yourActivityName"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"/>
```